# R-markdown to create multiple word file parametrised from excel tab

Tags: r, excel, ms-word, r-markdown

I have a table in Excel that looks like this:

| Country | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 01 | A |
| UK | 02 | B |
| FR | 03 | C |

Using R (I imported the excel using "readxl" package) and Rmarkdown, I would like to create, for each country, a word file showing only the X and Y values related to that country. So for example, the word file generated for the US would have "US" as title, and simply a table showing:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | A |

Can anybody help? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a rmarkdown document:

````
---
title: "`r Country`"
output: word_document
---

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(df_xy, row.names = FALSE)
```
````

In a separate .R file set up a loop to render the rmarkdown files with required data.

In your use case just substitute `df1` with the output from `readxl::read_xlsx()`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Country = rep(c("US", "UK", "FR"), each = 3),
                  X = rep(c("01", "02", "03"), each = 3),
                  Y = LETTERS[1:9])


for (Country in unique(df1$Country)) {
  
  df_xy <- df1[df1$Country == Country, c("X", "Y")]
  
  rmarkdown::render(
    'country_xy.Rmd',
    output_file =  paste0(Country, '.docx')
    
  )
}
```

You should end up with, in this case, three files:

- FR.docx
- UK.docx
- US.docx

Which results in a WORD file as so:

[image]

A really useful resource for rmarkdown is: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rmarkdown-render.html